# Bug copying item with Literalpath or intended?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following really simple code:

```
Try {
    Copy-Item -Path '\\server\g$\thisfolder\thisfiledoesntexist.ini' -Destination 'c:\temp' -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    "Ran into an issue: $_"
}
```

This will work fine to trap the error for a non-existent souce file. However the following will not - there's no error generated.

```
Try {
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\server\g$\thisfolder\thisfiledoesntexist.ini' -Destination 'c:\temp' -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    "Ran into an issue: $_"
}
```

However...this WILL trap the error

```
Try {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\server\g$\thisfolder\thisfiledoesntexist.ini' -ErrorAction Stop | Copy-Item
}
Catch {
    "Ran into an issue: $_"
}
```

This is the first time I've had occasion to use Literal paths - is this behaviour intended/expected?

Comment: Why are you using single quotes where there is a variable in the string, or is the share really called `g$` ?

Comment: I see the same behavior with both `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` until paths are also the same. Removing `\\?\UNC` should help.

Comment: @Theo That's a standard Windows' admin share

Comment: LiteralPath is supposed to use that format, when copying files using this format it bypasses character limit on paths

Comment: Gets stranger, see above. Get-ChildItem will trap the error

Comment: @montonero That is not clear in the question. For all we know, it may be a variable storing a sharename like `userstuff` or something.

Comment: @Theo  Powershell variables are started with $, not ended.

Comment: @montonero Ah, damn.. need bigger glasses. I see now. Thanks.

Comment: @Theo No worries B-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a bug with `Copy-Item` under Windows PowerShell. It seems including a `?` character anywhere in input for either `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` stops an error from being trapped for a non-existent path.

The bug seems to have been fixed on PowerShell Core, where your code above does result in an exception being caused.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to try on Core. 
I've written my code to test for the path first as a workaround - I seem to recall that MS isn't going to do much more to Windows Powershell and is focusing on Core?

Comment: Well they've said they won't do new feature development for Windows PowerShell, but would potentially do bug fixes, although I don't know whether they'd consider it a serious enough bug to warrant fixing. You're correct the PowerShell Core is now the focus.